# Numeric field being treated as varchar. Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '24.00' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm having trouble with this piece of SQL:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN u.password IS NULL 
          THEN 'GUEST' 
          ELSE 'CUSTOMER' 
     END) as STATUS, 
    u.date_created, u.name as UserName, u.password, u.email, 
    r.token as Currency, 
    (CASE 
       WHEN u.balance > 0 
         THEN LEFT(u.balance, LEN(u.balance) - 2) + '.' + RIGHT(u.balance, 2)
         ELSE 0 
     END) as Balance
FROM 
    [user] u
INNER JOIN 
    [region] r ON r.currency_id = u.balance_currency
```

It is showing this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '24.00' to data type int.

It started happening when i added the line:

```
(CASE WHEN u.balance >0 THEN left(u.balance,len(u.balance)-2)+'.'+right(u.balance,2)
ELSE 0 END) as Balance
```

This line tries to turn u.balance, which has values like 2400, to 24.00 only when the value is greater than 0. It is a numerical(10,0) field, so i'm not sure why it's using 24.00 and considering it a varchar. Any help will be greatly appreciated! THanks!

Comment: If u.balance is numeric, cast it to a varchar before attempting string functions.

Comment: Why do you need to do this calculation instead of a simple `balance / 100`?

Comment: @dnoeth, that was perfecto. \m/

Answer (score 1):

`case`expression should return the same data types. In this case use `'0'` instead of numeric value `0`, because you are returning a `varchar` in `when`.

```
CASE WHEN u.balance >0 THEN left(u.balance,len(u.balance)-2)+'.'+right(u.balance,2)
ELSE '0' END
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, storing numbers as strings is generally a bad idea.  I think you can get the desired behavior by doing something like this:

```
(case when isnumeric(u.balance) = 0
      then '0'
      when cast(u.balance as float) > 0.0
      then stuff(u.balance, len(u.balance - 2), 0, '.')
      else '0'
 end)
```

However, I would encourage you to reconsider storing numbers as strings.

Note:  You can fix your version of the code just by using `0.0` for the constant rather than `0`.